# The time is a type of energy ?

Tags: energy, time

You know energy is necessary for the occurrence of an event . Time is also exactly neccessary for the occurrence of an event. If there is no time , there will be no event. I mean time is a type of energy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time is only a coordinate, just like x,y,z etc (up, forward, right etc). 
Just as you use these coordinates to locate the position of an event in space, you have to use time $t$ to locate it in time. In fact, Einstein's relativity suggests that time is treated exactly like another dimension of space, implying the not unpopular idea that the universe is a 4-dimensional block of 'space-time'. Now if we adopt this idea, we now say that an event is just a point in 'space-time' and so its more like a location.

Energy, meanwhile, is a tricksy quantity but I prefer to think of it as the ability to do 'work' (basically assert a force over a distance). You can have energy even if nothing is happening per se. This is called potential energy, and as the name suggests it is the potential for work to occur. A ball held in the air has the potential to move downwards in earth's gravity.

Does this make things clearer?

TLDR: Basically, time is a location coordinate and not an inherent ability to do work.